# Where to store object information django?

Tags: python, django, templates, session

In my Django project I need to access constantly the object of the user`s *character*(a model), **where should I store the value of this object ?** since I will be using it in multiple views to display content in the template. Should I store in the session, retrieve from the database every time or some other alternative?

```
class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    gold = models.IntegerField(default=gold)
    points = models.IntegerField(default = startPoints)
```

Comment: Why not use cache?, it seems the better for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly means `character`, but:
If it is not session-based, but permanent information(and I believe that it is) you need to store it in the database to be able to fetch it when the user log in. How you will store it does not really matter - it can be dedicated table if you need it(in this case would be nice to add user as FK) or it could be a field in `User` table.

Then, if you have Session middleware and Authentication middleware, you will be able to access `user` object from the request object, so what you will need to do is:
`request.user.character`

I hope it is helpful.

UPD: the only way to store the data between requests in DB or caching system(if you have non-DB cache or you don't store session in DB but in something faster instead - like Redis or Memcache). I am adraid that is the only way.

For per-session data you can use cookies in some situation, but I think it isn't the case.

Comment: It's a matter of retrieving the value of the model, I didn't want to go in the database every time since the value is used often, in the way its implemented I can't access it by request.user.character

Comment: well, it is a field in the model it will be fetched anyway if you have 'auth' and 'session' middlewares enabled - so it won't add more requests to DB.

Comment: @VictorFerreira I also updated my answer, please check